# Mobile version elemental theme Concrete5 v 5.7

Tags: css, web, concrete5

I am making a website with concrete 5.7. and to edit some things i have copied the Elemental theme and created my theme. But there are two things i don't know how to edit:

1)Is there a way to define how the elements are going to be disposed in mobile version or at least at which size the autonav is going to be changed by the menu button?Also in small screens the logo becomes really small and all the elements appear disordered.(attached file shows those problems)

2) When i change the colors of my website,(settings->design->customize) where does this changes store, because for me it would be easier to use a text editor rather than doing it with the tool. I don't want to create a new color preset, only to know where these changes are stored.
Thanks for everything.!
Photo: https://plus.google.com/photos/109724001772064952270/albums/6114581190555851105 The first one is the original and the other is the mobile version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually a bit complex. In the elemental folder, there's a css folder. Inside that folder there's a bootstrap-modified.css file that is responsible for many things including the grid. As the name suggests, it is minified so hard to read and modify.

You also have a file called main.less and several folders containing a lot of other less files.
main.less gets processed and compiled into a css file on the fly, meaning when the site is visited and the css file was not generated yet or when less files were modified.

Anything you want modified you should modify in the less files.

Look for media queries "@media" to find styles specific to certain screen sizes.

Comment: Thx! that was what i was looking for. I had tried to modified the bootstrap-modified and didn't saw any changes. I will try with less. Also if someone is looking for a more complex solution here is what i found [link](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 0):

how elements are disposed in mobile version is really something you need to deal with through the use of CSS. It is not really something Concrete5 has control over.

The changes to design made through settings->design->customize are saved in the database.

BUT the things you can modify are defined in the site's css file. You could simply modify the css file directly using any text editor instead of customizing design through the dashboard.

Comment: Yeah, but which files/lines of css modified the mobile version. I have been looking over the files and i couldn't find it. You know if the mobile version  are the ones with the <?php if ($displayThirdColumn) { ?> ?.